# Is there any difference between defining and declaring variables in javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables

It may seem very trivial issue but very confusing and recurring for me. In some manuals for javascript or tutorials these terms are used alternately.
In others I found the explanation that we **declare** variables when we create them with `var` `const` `let` and we **define** variables, when we append some value/object to the declared variable as below:

```
var name; //declaring
name = 'Adam' //defining
var age = 'dead' //declaring + defining
```

Are there any approved and correct rules of using these two terms?

Comment: The first line technically does define the variable as `undefined`, which is a valid primitive data type in JS. The second line actually re-defines the variable to the string 'Adam'.

Comment: @skyline3000 right!

Comment: note, there is an important difference between `var` and `let`

Comment: You might want to look up the term _variable hoisting_.

Comment: If the variable is not previously declared, then defining it (e.g. `name = 'Adam';`) will implicitly declare it in the global scope.  For instance, if this example were running in a browser, then `name` would be attached to the `window` object, rather than declared in the scope of the function where it is defined.

Comment: The description of "define" vs "declare" in your question is accurate. Of course, the computer doesn't care what you call it.

Comment: Technical details between programming languages aside, I don't think any programmer would be confused by the terminology you're using - it's pretty much the standard in all modern languages. As I mentioned in the first comment though, just note the small nuance with `undefined` in JS since not all languages have that concept.

Comment: Basically you just use the `var` the first time the variable is used and you have the option of also assigning a value with the assignment operator `=`. Of course you need to be mindful of the scoping as mentioned by everyone else. So, no hard and fast rules.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that "*variable definition*" is not a standard JavaScript term.

Functions (of all kinds) and object properties can get *defined*, but variables always get *declared*. This terminology might hint at the declarative nature of variables - a declaration always applies to the complete current scope, it's not an action that gets executed and does something.

`var name` is a declaration. `var age = 'dead'` is a declaration with an initialiser. `name = 'Adam'` is just an assignment. I'd guess that "defining" a variable refers to it no longer being `undefined`, so both an assignment statement or the initialiser of the declaration might do that. I'd rather speak of the *initialisation* of the variable, though.

Answer (score 0):

`var x` is a declaration because you are not defining what value it holds but you are declaring its existence and the need for memory allocation.

`var x = 1` is both declaration and definition but are separated with `x` being declared in the beginning while its definition comes at the line specified (variable assignments happen inline).

I see that you already understand the concept of `hoisting` but for those that don't, Javascript takes every variable and function declaration and brings it to the top (of its corresponding scope) then trickles down assigning them in order.

You seem to know most of this already though. Here's a great resource if you want some advanced, in-depth exploration. Yet I have a feeling you've been there before.

[**Javascript Garden**](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/)